# How implement a LiveData Singleton

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I need to pass a Bitmap between activities **without** write the image in the internal/external memory.

An Intent can't carry that size so the best option that I found is to use a Singleton Bitmap or extend Livedata and use it as singleton. 
(I'm not that good with architecture so if you have a better solution...)

I'm trying to implement the LiveData option since the livedata observer will be useful and I'm following the
[official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#extend_livedata):

```
class StockLiveData(symbol: String) : LiveData<BigDecimal>() {
private val stockManager: StockManager = StockManager(symbol)

private val listener = { price: BigDecimal ->
    value = price
}

override fun onActive() {
    stockManager.requestPriceUpdates(listener)
}

override fun onInactive() {
    stockManager.removeUpdates(listener)
}

companion object {
    private lateinit var sInstance: StockLiveData

    @MainThread
    fun get(symbol: String): StockLiveData {
        sInstance = if (::sInstance.isInitialized) sInstance else StockLiveData(symbol)
        return sInstance
    }
}
```

}

But I really don't understand the logic:

- What's the listener will be used for?
- What's the class StockManager?
- If I need it only for a Bitmap do I need to use onActive() and onInactive() too?

I couldn't find a different implementation example anywhere, how can I implement that only for a Bitmap?

------------ UPDATE for the Sanlok Lee answer ----------------

I tried to implement your class BitmapCache example:

In my first activity I attach the observer

```
    companion object {
         val myCache = BitmapCache()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)

        myCache.getCachedBitmap().observe(this, Observer<Bitmap> { selfie: Bitmap? ->
        Log.i(TAG, "TRIGGERED")
    })
```

And in my second Activity I set the value like that:

```
    companion object {
        val myCache = BitmapCache()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)

        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            myCache.cacheBitmap(bitmap)
        }, 3000)
}
```

But the observer is never triggered, are you sure I can create a Live data singleton like that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`StockManager` in the example is just a random custom class they made just for example purpose.

Just to give you a simpler example that uses a more familiar component, let's imagine that you need to create a custom `LiveData` that count (and emit the count) the number of user button press while the `LiveData` is active. It can look like this:

```
class ButtonClickLiveData(val button: Button) : LiveData<Int>() {

    var clickCount = 0

    private val listener = { v: View ->
        clickCount++
        value = clickCount
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        // Set the click listener when LiveData is not active.
        button.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        // Remove the click listener when LiveData is not active.
        button.setOnClickListener(null)
    }
}
```

And to explain your question

- What's the listener will be used for?

That listener will be attached to the `StockManager`. When there is any change in `StockManager`, `StockManager` class is responsible for invoking this listener, and when the listener is invoked, it will update `LiveData` value.

- What's the class StockManager?

Just an example class.

- If I need it only for a Bitmap do I need to use onActive() and onInactive() too?

No. In fact I am guessing you would not need `LiveData` for transporting large object. Just as you pointed out, a simple singleton cache class is all you need. `LiveData` would make sense if you have a stream of `Bitmap` and you want the activities to automatically react to the stream. For example:

```
class BitmapCache {  // This can be a singleton class.

   private val bitmapLiveData = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>()

   fun cacheBitmap(bmp: Bitmap) {
       bitmapLiveData.value = bmp
   }

   fun getCachedBitmap(): LiveData<Bitmap> = bitmapLiveData as LiveData<Bitmap>
}
```

---

**Edit**:
Here's the singleton version of the class:

```
object BitmapCache {

    private val bitmapLiveData = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>()

    fun cacheBitmap(bmp: Bitmap) {
        bitmapLiveData.value = bmp
    }

    fun getCachedBitmap(): LiveData<Bitmap> = bitmapLiveData as LiveData<Bitmap>
}
```

and it can be used like this:

```
// Activity A
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)

        BitmapCache.getCachedBitmap().observe(this, Observer<Bitmap> { selfie: Bitmap? ->
        Log.i(TAG, "TRIGGERED")
    })

// Activity B
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)

        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            BitmapCache.cacheBitmap(bitmap)
        }, 3000)
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, let me test that, I'll do it asap!

Comment: I tried to implement your answer but the observer is never triggered, I updated the question explaining how I implemented you answer.

Comment: I don't think your BitmapCache is a working Livedata singleton, the doc explicitly say that you have to extend livedata for do that.

Comment: @GMX Please check if you have correctly implemented singleton class. The `BitmapCache` class example I provided you omitted singleton implementation for simplicity. You must provide the same instance of `BitmapCache` class to all activities.